# angular 2, How to access deep links when building and serving app with http-server?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an app that I want to serve and it works well until someone wants to access a deep link and they get a 404.

When running angular-cli command `ng serve` I have no problem with deep links.
But I cannot use angular-cli commands outside my local environment.

However when I run `ng build` then `http-server ./dist` ([server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server))  I can access the url `localhost:8080` and my login page shows up.

I attempt to access a deep link `localhost:8080/page` I am returned a 404.

Would anybody be able to advise how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this particular `http-server` handles the *HTML5 routing*. However, the oldschool servers like `nginx` can be configured to serve URLs the way you want.

It's also worth noting you have to have the `base-href` element [set up properly](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) in your `index.html`.

---

Eg. in case of `nginx` there is [an option](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) called `try_files`. It tries to resolve all the given options until successful.

*Angular 2's* HTML5 routes can be resolved with: `try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;`.